# Why do I get this output with psmatrix?

Tags: graphs, psmatrix

I'm trying to draw some graph using the `psmatrix` package. The output is justas expected except for that circle down left. First I thought it to be the empty node (4th row, first column) with no content but if I remove the code for the edges, it disappears. What is causing this "glitch"?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\begin{center}
$
\psmatrix[colsep=1.5cm,rowsep=1cm,mnode=circle]
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
& 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\ncline{->}{2,2}{1,2}
\ncline{->}{1,2}{1,1}
\ncline{->}{1,1}{2,1}
\ncline{->}{2,1}{3,1}
\ncline{->}{2,1}{3,1}
\ncline{->}{3,1}{3,2}
\ncline{->}{3,2}{4,2}
\ncline{->}{4,2}{4,3}
\ncline{->}{4,3}{4,4}
\ncline{->}{4,4}{3,4}
\ncline{->}{3,4}{2,4}
\ncline{->}{2,4}{1,4}
\ncline{->}{1,4}{1,3}
\ncline{->}{1,3}{2,3}
\ncline{->}{2,3}{3,3}%
\ncline[nodesep=5pt]{<->}{2,1}{2,2}
\ncline[nodesep=5pt]{<->}{2,2}{2,3}
\ncline[nodesep=5pt]{<->}{2,2}{3,2}
\ncline[nodesep=5pt]{<->}{3,2}{3,3}
\ncline[nodesep=5pt]{<->}{3,3}{4,3}
\ncline[nodesep=5pt]{<->}{3,3}{3,4}
\endpsmatrix$ 
\end{center}
```

And the preamble just in case:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-tree,pstricks-add}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was because you ended your psmatrix with a new empty row. I took the opportunity to remove unnecessary packages: `graphics` (`graphicx` loads it), `color` (`pstricks` loads `xcolor`), `pstricks`and `pst-node` (`pstricks-add` loads them). Iadded `auto-pst-pdf` to compile with `pdflatex`. Finally, I simplified the code with the `foreach` command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pst-tree,pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} %% to compiile with pdflatex -shell-escape (TeX Live, MacTeX)
                                                 %% or pdflatex --enable-write18 (MiKTeX)
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

  \[
    \begin{psmatrix}[colsep=1.5cm,rowsep=1cm,mnode=circle]
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
& 0 & 1 & 0
%% horizontal arrows
\foreach \B/\E in{{1,2}/{1,1}, {1,4}/{1,3}, {3,1}/{3,2}, {4,2}/{4,3}, {4,3}/{4,4}}{\ncline[arrows=->, nodesep=5pt]{\B}{\E}}
%% vertical arrows
\foreach \B/\E in{{1,1}/{2,1}, {2,1}/{3,1}, {2,2}/{1,2}, {3,2}/{4,2}, {1,3}/{2,3}, {2,3}/{3,3}, {2,4}/{1,4}, {3,4}/{2,4}, {4,4}/{3,4}}%
{\ncline[arrows=->, nodesep=5pt]{\B}{\E}}
%% double arrows
\foreach \B/\E in{{2,1}/{2,2},{2,2}/{2,3},{2,2}/{3,2}, {3,2}/{3,3},{3,3}/{4,3},{3,3}/{3,4}}%
{\ncline[arrows=<->, nodesep=5pt]{\B}{\E}}
\end{psmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see, this environment is just too sensitive to spaces inside it. Also thanks for the thing about package imports. And wow I didn't even know LaTeX has a `foreach` thing (seemed too "user-friendly" for LaTeX's standards I never bothered to check). Great answer.

Comment: It's not a problem of white spaces (except blank lines), but you explicitly ended your psmatrix with `\\ `.  the `\foreach` command is borrowed from package `pgffor`. It can be simpler to use than `multido` in some situations.